# flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show

Tags: android, flutter

My flutter app, show this notification when FCM is triggered.

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
  0, "my app. Alert", "Alert text from App", platform
);
```

Is there any way to show a image in the notification bar and not only the text?

Something like:

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
  0, "my app. Alert", "Alert text from App","url: myimage.com/sample.jpg", platform
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-readme-tab-) plugin, then you can do something like this for android:

```
Future<void> _showBigPictureNotification() async {
    var largeIconPath = await _downloadAndSaveImage(
        'http://via.placeholder.com/48x48', 'largeIcon');
    var bigPicturePath = await _downloadAndSaveImage(
        'http://via.placeholder.com/400x800', 'bigPicture');
    var bigPictureStyleInformation = BigPictureStyleInformation(
        bigPicturePath, BitmapSource.FilePath,
        largeIcon: largeIconPath,
        largeIconBitmapSource: BitmapSource.FilePath,
        contentTitle: 'overridden <b>big</b> content title',
        htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
        summaryText: 'summary <i>text</i>',
        htmlFormatSummaryText: true);
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'big text channel id',
        'big text channel name',
        'big text channel description',
        style: AndroidNotificationStyle.BigPicture,
        styleInformation: bigPictureStyleInformation);
    var platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, null);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'big text title', 'silent body', platformChannelSpecifics);
  }
```

For more such examples, please refer the official example provided by the plugin developer, [here](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart).